# Calculo de valor entre datas para campos input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Pessoal não sei nada de java e acredito que é o que vou precisar. Seguinte situação:

Abaixo o script pra gerar o valor com juros e multa do valor entre data de vencimento e data de pagamento e seus respectivos campos:

```
<input name="form_fatura_datapag" type="text" value="<?php if ($coluna[fatura_datapag]=='0') echo date('d/m/Y'); else echo inteirodata(@mysql_result($sql,0,fatura_datapag));?>" size="15"/>

<input name="form_fatura_valor" type="text" value="<?= number_format($valorDocComJuros,2,",",".");?>" size="15"/>


<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faturas WHERE id_fatura=$_GET[id]");
while ($coluna = @mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$dat_venc = inteirodata($coluna[fatura_data]);
if ($coluna[fatura_datapag]=='0') $dat_novo_venc = date('d/m/Y'); else $dat_novo_venc = inteirodata($coluna[fatura_datapag]); //CALCULO DE JUROS E MULTA DEIXA DE SER CALCULADO QDO SE COLOCA DATA DE PAGAMENTO
$valor_doc = "$coluna[fatura_parcela]";

$juros =  (((($valor_doc*1)/100)/30 * (diasEntreData($dat_venc,$dat_novo_venc ))));

if(diasEntreData($dat_venc,$dat_novo_venc)==0)
{$multa = 0;}
else
{$multa = ((2 * $valor_doc) / 100);}//Moeda(($valor_doc * 2) / 100);

$valorDocComJuros = $valor_doc + ($juros + $multa);
?>
```

No caso ele vai ter que fazer calculo entre duas datas, data 1=vencimento e data 2= de pagamento e gerar o valor da fatura automatico no input com juros da diferença desta data.

Exemplo fatura `10,00` vencimento `30/01/2016`

Hoje a fatura ta em `10,15` colocando a data de pagamento de ontem `02/02/2016` ele registra  valor no banco de dados de `10,15` e não `10,10` como deveria ser pago na data de ontem.

Comment: Opa, acredito que esteja faltando alguns dados na sua dúvida amigo.
Ah, aproveitando a oportunidade, lhe indico conhecer um pouco mais o funcionamento do SOpt. Acesse http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e realize o tour de boas-vindas.

Comment: Mas você tem certeza que o seu problema está com a tag certa? Vejo tanto código PHP aí que não consigo associar nada com a realidade de Java.

Comment: Parece que era pra ser javascript.

Comment: Bem pessoal, coloquei o que tinha feito em PHP, mas acredito que o caculo feito dentro dos inputs deve ser em java, claro que posso estar enganado.